# Atlassian-connect: Error on 'installed' event

Tags: node.js, macos, jira, atlassian-connect

I'm trying to run [example Jira add-on](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-connect-express-template). 
I have created `credentials.json` file and have run `npm i` and `node app.js`.

But I have problems with `installed` event. Here is nodejs log:

```
Watching atlassian-connect.json for changes
Add-on server running at http://MacBook-Air.local:3000
Initialized sqlite3 storage adapter
Local tunnel established at https://a277dbdf.ngrok.io/
Check http://127.0.0.1:4040 for tunnel status
Registering add-on...
GET /atlassian-connect.json 200 13.677 ms - 784
Saved tenant details for 608ff294-74b9-3edf-8124-7efae2c16397 to database
{ key: 'my-add-on',
  clientKey: '608ff294-74b9-3edf-8124-7efae2c16397',
  publicKey: 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCtKxrEBipTMXhRHlv9zcSLR2Y9h5YQgNQ5vpJ40tF9RmuIzByjkKTurCLHFwMAWU6aLQM+H+Z8wAlpL9AVlN5NKrEP8+a3mGFUOj/5nSJ7ZWHjgju0sqUruyEkKLvKuhWkKkd9NqBxogN0hxv7ue5msP5ezwei/nTJXmnmA5qOAQIDAQAB',
  sharedSecret: 'LfT9elHM7iHkto5pHr+MnpH0SR1ypunIDoCyt6ugVJ1Q4hWHurG8k5DjVzLcvT2C98DDbiJiA89VNB0e3DiUvQ',
  serverVersion: '100075',
  pluginsVersion: '1.3.407',
  baseUrl: 'https://gleb-olololololo-22.atlassian.net',
  productType: 'jira',
  description: 'Atlassian JIRA at https://gleb-olololololo-22.atlassian.net ',
  eventType: 'installed' }
POST /installed?user_key=admin 204 51.021 ms - -
Failed to register with host https://gleb-olololololo-22%40yopmail.com:gleb-olololololo-22@gleb-olololololo-22.atlassian.net (200)
The add-on host did not respond when we tried to contact it at "https://a277dbdf.ngrok.io/installed" during installation (the attempt timed out). Please try again later or contact the add-on vendor.
{"type":"INSTALL","pingAfter":300,"status":{"done":true,"statusCode":200,"contentType":"application/vnd.atl.plugins.task.install.err+json","errorMessage":"The add-on host did not respond when we tried to contact it at \"https://a277dbdf.ngrok.io/installed\" during installation (the attempt timed out). Please try again later or contact the add-on vendor.","source":"https://a277dbdf.ngrok.io/atlassian-connect.json","name":"https://a277dbdf.ngrok.io/atlassian-connect.json"},"links":{"self":"/rest/plugins/1.0/pending/80928cb9-f64e-42d0-9a7e-a1fe8ba81055","alternate":"/rest/plugins/1.0/tasks/80928cb9-f64e-42d0-9a7e-a1fe8ba81055"},"timestamp":1513692335651,"userKey":"admin","id":"80928cb9-f64e-42d0-9a7e-a1fe8ba81055"}
Add-on not registered; no compatible hosts detected
```

I have reviewed tons of information in Google, but didn't found an answer.

More details, that can helps you to answer.

It happens suddenly. It worked OK, but about 1 week ago I start to get this error and cannot fix it. So I didn't change anything, just run add-on again, as I did it every day.

If I try to upload add-on manually I got error in terminal

```
GET / 302 17.224 ms - 0
GET /atlassian-connect.json 200 2.503 ms - 783
Found existing settings for client 608ff294-74b9-3edf-8124-7efae2c16397. Authenticating reinstall request
Authentication verification error: 401 Could not find authentication data on request
POST /installed?user_key=admin 401 22.636 ms - 45
```

The most possible reason (that I've found in google) is that I have wrong server time. But the time on my local machine is correct (at least for my timezone).

Anyone has any thoughts about this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't set up another persistent store in the config.json file then try deleting the sqlite db file in the root of your folder.  It's called store.db and try npm start again.  I find that the sqlite db file gets out of sync and needs a refresh from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I kept randomly having this happen to me. It would be working, then run `npm start` and I would get the error. Since I'm not using a database right now, I simply removed all references to the juggling-sqlite database. This was in `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, `config.json`, and I just removed `store.db`. That got it working for me. Pretty frustrating that this happens, not sure a better way around it.